# Trying to get Video player to work

Tags: totem

From the thread:  [Totem fails with missing plugins after 22.04 LTS upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423522/totem-fails-with-missing-plugins-after-22-04-lts-upgrade)

Trying to decipher the answer, but am unsure how to do this.

How do you remove ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0?

Answer (score 1):

Delete it with `rm -r ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0` command in terminal app.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly and thank you for teaching me :)